# Jboos connectivity Issue

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, infinispan

I am getting the following error when trying to connect my application to jboss:

> WARN | ISPN004022: Unable to invalidate transport for server:
>   /127.0.0.1:12222 ERROR | ISPN004017: Could not fetch transport
>   org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.TransportException:: Could not
>   connect to server: /127.0.0.1:12222

Tried searching a lot for a solution. It would be great is someone could help me out with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must recall the following actions:

1. Make sure that your webapp is using the same port as defined in the **socket-binding** definitions for hotrod in the **standalone.xml** for JDG configuration folder;
2. Make sure that your webapp is using the proper inject annotations for your `RemoteCacheManager` class (remember to use the `@ApplicationScopped` annotation at the class definition and for additional methods used to get the cache instance);
3. If you are using JBoss and JDG on the same host, you must check declarations of the `JBOSS_HOME` environment variable. This variable must be assigned to the JDG installation home directory and not the JBoss EAP home (check also port-offset settings at startup if you're using a custom shell script);
4. If you are not using both products on the same host, check firewall and network settings;
5. Remember to re-deploy the application always after every modification and check both EAP and JDG console output for warnings and/or errors.

The following errors are related (for example):

```
14:38:42,610 WARN  [org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory] (http-127.0.0.1:8080-1) ISPN004022: 
Unable to invalidate transport for server: /127.0.0.1:11322

14:38:42,610 ERROR [org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory] (http-127.0.0.1:8080-1) ISPN004017: 
Could not fetch transport: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool not open
```